# Highchart Legend rendering issue on Linux browsers

Tags: highcharts, donut-chart

Highchart Legend rendering issue on Linux browsers, I think issue Happens in font family in highcharts. how to add custom font family to legend

Below added my code

```
 title: {
        text: c,
        widthAdjust: -180
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
    },
    legend: {

       itemStyle: {
                   width:'100px',
                   color: '#666',
                   textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                   overflow: 'hidden'
       }

    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the font family of the legend, you need to set `fontFamily` of [`legend.itemStyle`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemStyle) like this:

```
legend: {
  itemStyle:{
    fontFamily: 'Comic Sans MS'
  } 
}
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/sc3Lnfa9/5/